# C++:Passing pointer class parameter in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

```
    class MySqlDbFactory: public DbDatabaseFactory{
      public:
             IConnection* CreateConnection(){
             return new  MySqlDbConnection();
             }

             ICommand* CreateCommand(){
             return new MySqlDbCommand();
             }
      };

class Factory{
          DbDatabaseFactory* _databaseFactory;
          IConnection* _connection;
          ICommand* _command;
  public:
          Factory(DbDatabaseFactory*);

       void Start(){
           _connection->Connect();
            if(_connection->connectionState == true){
            _command->Execute("SELECT ...");
            }
      };


  };

Factory::Factory(DbDatabaseFactory* dbFactory)
  {
      _databaseFactory = dbFactory;   
      _connection = dbFactory->CreateConnection();
     _command = dbFactory->CreateCommand();
  } 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MySqlDbFactory* mySQlFactory = new MySqlDbFactory();
    Factory factory = new Factory(mySQlFactory); ...
```

I have an error

> conversion from `Factory*' to non-scalar type`Factory' requested
>   on

```
  Factory factory = new Factory(mySQlFactory); line.
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's:

```
Factory* factory = new Factory(mySQlFactory);
```

(Note the `*` after `Factory`)

Comment: Code is compiled thank you but when I call the Start method of Factory as  factory.Start(); it says `Start' has not been declared. Do you have suggestion about this one?

Comment: I would advise you to take some basic c++ tutorials. Answer is: factory->Start(); this is needed because factory is a pointer to a Factory object.

Comment: In this context, it's enough to write `MySqlDbFactory mySqlFactory;` no `new` needed. (Then you can also spare the dereference `->`)